# Concept of modprobe and module dependancies

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, insmod

As modprobe looks through modules.dep for dependancies,is it necessary to execute depmod before modprobe?plz help me with module inserting process

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/11/modprobe-command-examples/

Comment: @Jeyaram When the kernel needs a feature that is not resident in the kernel, the kernel module daemon kmod execs modprobe to load the module in but in that ex why modprobe was executed by user?

Comment: If the user don't have idea about dependency for particular kernel module.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to execute `depmod` whenever the dependecies (might) have changed.

Usually, `depmod` is executed automatically when new modules are installed.